# How do I avoid the Eye of Cthulu?

Tags: terraria

How do you avoid getting hit by the Eye of Cthulhu?

I can't get any wings.I find it frustrating that I can't avoid him. Is there a easy wingless suggestion to defeat this boss? My computer wont let me look this up on google.

Comment: Why can't you get wings?

Comment: @n_palum wings are hard mode items. If you have wings in Terraria there is no way the Eye of Cthulhu is a threat to you.

Comment: Did you read any of the suggestions from the linked question? That seems to be exactly what you want. As a side note, telling us your computer won't let you search isn't an excuse to do no research.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to get wings for a fight with the Eye of Cthulhu because they are hard mode items and will only be obtainable after defeating the Wall of Flesh in Hell.

To answer how to deal with the Eye of Cthulhu you should try and obtain mobility items such as the bottle items that give you double jumps and find Hermes Boots in order to outrun the eye when it attacks. It also helps to create a boss arena out of platforms above the ground so you have a long straight area with multiple levels to help you avoid the Eye's attacks.

It also helps to have ranged weaponry at your disposal as well since getting close to the Eye of Cthulhu is a really bad idea, especially in his enraged mode which deals more damage to you when he touches you. Make yourself some fire arrows and get a decent bow and take pot shots at the eye while running from it on your arena and you'll have a better chance of surviving the encounter.